# Meaning of E^2 / Z

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

I am reading [this paper](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Boris.Thibert/Publications/NashKuiperProcess_actes.pdf) , and I am stuck on a line on page 2 that reads:

> The geometry of the limit map consists merely of the behavior of its tangent planes or, equivalently, of the properties of its Gauss map $n_\infty : \mathbb{E}^2/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb{E^3}$.

How should I interpret the domain $ \mathbb{E}^2/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It should be an infinite cylinder..

Comment: @Berci Could you say a little bit more? Is this implicitly $\mathbb{E}^2/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $n=1$? And how is this different from $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}$? Thanks!

Comment: The line above has the flat torus $\Bbb E^2/\Bbb Z^2$. Do a similar identification here, but with one coordinate.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}^n$ is frequently used to denote $\mathbb{R}^m$ endowed with the Euclidean metric. In this sense $\mathbb{E}^2/\mathbb{Z}$ is the same manifold as $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}$, but with an explicit choice of metric.

Comment: Have you thought about that possibility that this is just a typo and one should have $\mathbb E^2/\mathbb Z^2$ there?